# save and generate pdfs nodes with options

Tags: 7, views, files

I have a view that list a content type A with few fields,
For PDFs generation I choose [views_pdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) it works perfectly and it can generate for me pdfs with the desired fields.

Im behind two problems now that I don't know how to solve them :

1. I want to save the PDF in my server first, so when the user click on pdf link inside the view, it save the PDF first then download it.
2. The PDF should be generated following options chosen by user : "download a short version", "Download a long version", ...
   ( inside the view I thought to make different links and for each option I create its own view. is it the best idea, or I can pass arguements to the pdf ? )

What's your advice, should I continue with `views_pdf` or I must switch to [pdf](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf) for example...

Thanks in advance for your suggessions.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: Rules should allow you to save a PDF to the server. Step 4 on this page explains how to do so using Webforms (and Webform Rules), but it should work for node-generated PDFs: http://areatype.com/blog/create-email-pdf-files-drupal-webforms

Part 2: You can absolutely pass arguments to a Views PDF. Aren't you already doing that with the NID?